Gaining knowledge when you'd lose it: Opinion based? Fixable?
Gaining knowledge when you'd lose it
I don't particularly think this is more opinion-based than most questions. Obviously the most-clearly non-opinion-based questions are something like "what did Kant say about...", but the on-topic page makes explicit nod to things where there'd be reasonable disagreement with Is 'cogito ergo sum' false?.
It seems similar to other currently-open questions like What is the value of facts in philosophy?, to pick one at random. If there's a factors that makes it particularly opinion-based, what are they?
In any case, I took a stab at reorganizing it while hopefully keeping the meaning the same. If anyone has suggestions for other improvements or feels that there's reasons it is unfixable, let me know.

IMHO,  the first post simplifies to "What is the philosophocal justification for acquiring knowledge" The temporary existence portion of the post is meaningless since everyone dies. This question has been asked before so I consider it a duplicate.

@IdiosyncraticSoul Yes —  The fact that everyone dies is a tautology. The feeling I shall die is not

@Rushi "The feeling about death or dying is too close to being an opinion for me.

Yes.
Here are some like Q-As
Almost identical
What is the point of acquiring knowledge when time would take it away soon enough?
What is the point of Human Existence?
Is "what's the point?" the same as asking "what is the meaning of life"?
What is the point of philosophy if it is itself the fruit of words and that therefore is limited?
What is the point of staying alive if everyone dies eventually?
Further but related
What is the point of creating for an omniscient being?
Reading older works
My View
This should actually be a tag and the only justification for closing should be a dup to a near identical question
A possible tag that comes to mind is Camusianity (like Cartesisnism, Platonism, Christianity)

There is only one really serious philosophical problem and that is suicide. Deciding whether or not life is worth living is to answer the fundamental question in philosophy.


For every question type that is off-topic, there are a number of non-closed questions, proving nothing.
